# Mockito, what happens if I do not close my Mocked static method

Tags: java, mockito

```java
void givenStaticMethodWithNoArgs_whenMocked_thenReturnsMockSuccessfully() {
    MockedStatic<StaticUtils> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticUtils.class)
    utilities.when(StaticUtils::name).thenReturn("Eugen");
    assertThat(StaticUtils.name()).isEqualTo("Eugen");
    utilities.close();
}
```

Why do I even need to close it?

Comment: Who said that you need to close it?

Comment: @maio290 the [JavaDoc for `MockedStatic`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html) says so. When an interface extends `java.lang.AutoCloseable` this is generally a hint that you should call the `close()` method, otherwise you risk possible resource leaks or similar.

Answer (score 5):

As the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html) states:

> If this object is never closed, the static mock will remain active on
> the initiating thread

Since the class is actually implementing the [`AutoClosable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface, you can simply use the class in a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) - which is as recommend in the [javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks):

```
 assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
 try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
 mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
 assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
 mocked.verify(Foo::method);
 }
 assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
```

If you want the Mock to be active during all tests, you can simply never close the Mock. However, if you do so, I'd do it in an init-method and not in a test. If your tests however shall be independent and not show such behaviour, you need to close it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , when i didn't enclosed try inside try-with-resource, my subsequent TCs/Junits started failing, dont know what was the reason.